# How to predict my test image in tensorflow MLP Mnist example

Tags: python, tensorflow

I Have [Tensorflow  MLP Mnist example based](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/multilayer_perceptron.py) simple classifier, its classify face and no_face on RGB 32x32 images.

Code working good and calculating classification accuracy

```
Epoch: 0001 cost = 6.539309704
Epoch: 0002 cost = 0.868323514
Epoch: 0003 cost = 0.265693334
Optimization Finished!
Accuracy network: 0.8974359
```

Accuracy is calculated by this code:

```
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
#Calculate accuracy
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
print("Accuracy network:", accuracy.eval({x: data.Images_test, y: data.Labels_test}))
```

How I can run prediction with my own image in this model?

I have tryed this code:

```
    image_with_no_face_1 = cv2.imread('a.jpg').reshape(1,3072)
    image_with_no_face_2 = cv2.imread('b.jpg').reshape(1,3072)
    image_with_face = cv2.imread('c.jpg').reshape(1,3072)

    print("Face :", accuracy.eval({x: image_with_no_face_1, y: data.Labels_test}))
    print("Face :", accuracy.eval({x: image_with_no_face_2, y: data.Labels_test}))
    print("Face :", accuracy.eval({x: image_with_face, y: data.Labels_test}))
```

And get this values that not right

```
Epoch: 0002 cost = 1087.248228555
Epoch: 0003 cost = 837.800127911
Epoch: 0004 cost = 39.879899548
Epoch: 0005 cost = 461.961817526
Optimization Finished!
Accuracy network: 0.8974359
Face : 0.8974359
Face : 0.8974359
Face : 0.8974359
```

I think I should to use **tf.matmul()** or similar functions instead **tf.reduce_mean()** but I can't find any solutions that working with this project structure.

Comment: By "predict/prediction", do you want the yes/no answer for each image or do you want the accuracy? If you want the accuracy, what is `data.Labels_test` and why 0.897 is not the right accuracy?

Comment: I mean, I want to get calculated probability is face/ or no_face on my image.

0.897 is not the right accuracy because i get this value on image with face, and get same value on image with no face (black square)

Comment: So you would want `pred`, which is the probability, rather than `accuracy`, wouldn't you?

Comment: Yes, I want to get some value that characteristing probability face on the image.